# Spring Security: null Principal on pages accessible by anonymous and logged users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, keycloak, anonymous

I need that a page in my application can be accessed by both anonymous and logged in users.
The application is part of a SSO context, where Keycloak is in charge for authentication and the access control is managed by Spring Security.
Each application has its own client configured in Keycloak.

I need that:

1. anonymous users can access this page with no restrictions
2. users already authenticated on other applications in the SSO context should be immediately recognized, so that I can print the name of the logged user

So far, I always get null when I try to retrieve the Principal:

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
User = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

The strange thing is that if I navigate a secured page, the Principal is then populated; otherwise, it is always null.

Also following the indications from https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture (at the paragraph "Creating and Customizing Filter Chains") I continue to get a null Principal: it seems that there is no fallback filter intercepting all the URLS that are not matched by my configuration.

In the following, my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class MyConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/secure/**")
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/robot**");
    }
}
```

I also tried to setup a fallback configuration, obtaining always the same result.

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class BasicAuthConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**")
        .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

**>>> Update 1 <<<**

`super.configure(http)` in my security file calls this method of the class `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(keycloakCsrfRequestMatcher())
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter(), SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
        .logoutUrl("/sso/logout").permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
```

**>>> Update 2 <<<**

I report some details that emerged from a deeper analysis.

**a) Logs related to the creation of the filter chain (printed at startup):**

```
Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/js/**'], []
Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/actuator/**'], []
Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', DELETE]]]
Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for ExactUrl [processUrl='/']
Adding web access control expression 'authenticated', for Ant [pattern='/secure/**']
Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4c4cc360,
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6710a0e3,
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@685b095c,
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter@5aec45a0,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@a766049,
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter@3ac44e13,
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter@3829182c,
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3f20b0d8,
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@715bfed,
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter@67b72f63,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2719a5c3,
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@508bfcfe,
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@46aab01d,
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@152f7bc5]
```

**b) Logs appearing when calling a NON SECURED page**

```
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/js/**'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/actuator/**'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@d99b189. A new one will be created.
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', GET]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', POST]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'POST /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', PUT]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'PUT /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', DELETE]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'DELETE /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/login']
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/sso/login'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=Authorization, expectedHeaderValue=null]
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher@594f1699
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@e8fcd0e2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 968df9fb-cf20-4f16-9962-df78ee71a960; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', GET]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', POST]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'POST /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', PUT]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'PUT /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', DELETE]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'DELETE /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/secure/**'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Public object - authentication not attempted
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/login']
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/sso/login'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=Authorization, expectedHeaderValue=null]
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher@594f1699
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**c) Logs appearing when calling a SECURED page**

```
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/js/**'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/actuator/**'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@93b05922: Authentication: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@93b05922: Principal: f:891de36f-d7ef-48aa-b7eb-1089417e8a81:7A1062D9-3101-4CB7-84BC-81D2080263DC; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@15a225c4; Granted Authorities: ROLE_offline_access, ROLE_uma_authorization'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', GET]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', POST]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'POST /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', PUT]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'PUT /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', DELETE]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'DELETE /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/login']
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/sso/login'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=Authorization, expectedHeaderValue=null]
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher@594f1699
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@93b05922: Principal: f:891de36f-d7ef-48aa-b7eb-1089417e8a81:7A1062D9-3101-4CB7-84BC-81D2080263DC; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@15a225c4; Granted Authorities: ROLE_offline_access, ROLE_uma_authorization'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', GET]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', POST]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'POST /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', PUT]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'PUT /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/logout', DELETE]
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /edizione/4745' doesn't match 'DELETE /sso/logout'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/secure/**'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Public object - authentication not attempted
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /edizione/4745 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/login']
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/edizione/4745'; against '/sso/login'
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=Authorization, expectedHeaderValue=null]
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher@594f1699
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**Some considerations**

As far as I can see debugging the class `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(...)`, in the first case (NON SECURED page) the incoming request never attempts authentication since the following check

```
if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
```

always returns `TRUE` (for that page, in fact, authentication is not mandatory) and so the execution flow continues to the next filter, skipping the population of the context.

Comment: Is the page in question ignored by Spring Security (`web.ignoring().antMatchers("/thispage/**")`)? This could mean the request is not going through the security filter chain and the security context is not getting populated.

Comment: Thank you Eleftheria! 
The page we are discussing about is /index.htm and does not match any of the .igtnoring().antMatchers(...) patterns. I can't figure out why the Principal is always null when I arrive on this landing page from an application where I am authenticated, but if I go to a secured path the Principal gets a value...

Comment: Do you have any additional security configrations? Which version of Spring Boot / Spring Security are you using? Furthermore, I noticed that you are calling `super.configure(http);`.You typically don't need to do this because you are supplying a custom configuration for `HttpSecurity`

Comment: The only security configurations we have are those we posted in the original question.
We are using Spring Boot 2.1.16.RELEASE, Spring Security 2.3.7.RELEASE and Keycloak Spring Security Adapter4.0.0.Final.
We call super.configure(http); because we need the configuration provided by Keycloak.
Here below I provide the content of the super.configure(http);

Comment: I proceeded to write the method that is invoked in the post.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason why the SecurityContext is not being populated properly. Perhaps if you can debug and put at breakpoint in the `getFilters` method of `FilterChainProxy` it will reveal some more information. Things to look out for are 1) that  a `SecurityFilterChain` matches the request and 2) which filters are in the filter chain

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. We are digging deeper debugging the classes you pointed out. We are facing problems because we are using keycloak on a cluster of two nodes, where each application (client) share the session with the counterpart on the other node by means of Spring Session (Hazelcast). A very big mess... We'll let you know as soon as we discover something.

Comment: We have digged deeper (see the updated question): as far as we understood, the problem is that Spring Security is ignoring our request to "authenticate also the non-secured pages". Maybe that's the point: we don't know how to tell Spring Security to do something like this:
1) check LOCALLY (session) if the user the Principal is present
2) if yes, nothing to do
3) if no, invoke the `attemptAuthentication(request, response)` method

Comment: Thanks in advance to all those who can give some suggestions.